B1/B2 visa refused twice. Will my ESTA be approved?
I was denied B1/B2 visa twice 2002 and 2004. Subsequently US visas were issued 2005, 2007, 2010, 2014. No other refusals any country. Travelled to USA and UK several times and always stayed within immigration rules. Does my ESTA have a good chance of being approved?

Your question might get closed as opinion-based, but for completeness what is your citizenship and country of residence?

What’s the reason you applied for visas previously and can now apply for ESTA? Did your country of citizenship join the VWP since then? Or is there any other reason? What were the reasons for the initial refusals? Were the granted visas also B-1/B-2?

Applied for visa before because I was citizen of non-vwp country. Now have added  citizenship ie UK citizenship hence thinking to use vwp. The two refusals and subsequent visa approvals were all B1/B2. I have asked my original question cos I was unsure whether I could ever use ESTA after  any previous visa refusal.

@MoKing “Does an earlier visa refusal make you permanently ineligible for ESTA even after a change of citizenship?” may be a more well-defined question then?

@Relaxed Agree. I read so many posts where there seemed to be some confusion around  'eligible' 'ineligible' so I just tried to lay out my situation and hopefully get some advise to help me decide which route to take now - ESTA on my British passport or B1/B2 visa application.

You can pay 20 bucks and find out. You are not barred from VWP, if your ESTA is approved.

While the ESTA application form has “eligibility questions” which include asking whether you have had any visa refusals (answer is obviously Yes), answering Yes to any of those questions does not make you automatically ineligible. It will nearly certainly go to manual processing, but given your history, chances are pretty good IMHO.

@jcaron whether the chances are good depends in large part in why the earlier B visa applications were unsuccessful.  If they were refused because the applicant was deemed permanently inadmissible for some reason then the ESTA application will almost certainly also be unsuccessful.  This is probably rather unlikely, but since we don't know (as far as I've noticed) the reason for the earlier refusals, we can't rule it out.

@phoog I reckon "permanently inadmissible" would have precluded subsequent  visa grants in the same category and multiple entries into the usa. So, while one cannot be overly certain in advance, it sounds like I'd go with jcaron and update as events unfold. All the comments are still highly valuable to me as I'm no expert on these matters and could easily miss a rule or detail

@MoKing absolutely; I didn't read very carefully.  Also I posted that before seeing your answer.

I decided to call the US embassy in UK. Laid out my situation and the officer said I can use ESTA insofar as I've not had a criminal record nor visited any of the 'prohibited' countries. For the nenefit of others, I'll try to update this post per outcome of ESTA application and my experience at point of entry to US.
